# Is it legal in Oakland, CA for a master tenant to profit from a subtenant?

Tags: rental-property, rent, sublease

Can a master tenant in Oakland, CA charge a subtenant in a room a higher price than the value of the room based the proportion of the room size to the whole house?

I.e., if master tenant has been there many years at a now-lower-than-market rate, can the master tenant charge a current rate for a room and profit from it in Oakland, CA?

In this scenario, the room in question that would be rented out to a subtenant is not the room in which the master tenant lives (not subletting).

Example with numbers: is it ok in Oakland, CA for a master tenant to pay $2000 per month for a home with 4 bed rooms, and charge three subtenants $1000 for a room (one subtenant per room), where the master tenant would make $3000 in "revenue" from all three subtenants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a document from the city](https://cao-94612.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/Guide-to-Oakland-Rental-Housing-Laws.pdf), which says p. 16 that

> Oakland does not have an Ordinance or Regulation restricting the
> amount of rent a master tenant charges a subtenant.

This assumes that subletting is not prohibited by the lease.

Comment: It looks like things might change based on this: https://oaklandside.org/2021/04/28/oakland-landlords-could-raise-rents-if-a-tenant-illegally-sublets-proposal-says/